# How should I implement communication between instances in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, tree, encapsulation

I have two AVL trees, each sort the same data by different parameters (say, one of the trees actually stores the data, the other just points to it). In the example, the tree on the left sorts by the left digit and the tree on the right sorts by the right digit:

```
               58             64   
              /   \          /   \
            22     73      22     58
           /  \   /  \    /  \   /  \
          19  36 64  81  81  73 36  19
```

Say I want to remove an item (from both trees, as it's the same data), but I'm only given the number on the left. For example, after `removeLeft(6)` is called, my trees would look like:

```
               58             36   
              /   \          /   \
            22     73      22     58
           /  \      \    /  \      \
          19  36     81  81  73     19
```

I can find the node in the left tree in `log(n)` time, and if I'm at the node I wish to remove, I can remove it from each tree in another `log(n)` per tree.

However, I need a link from a node in the left tree to a node on the right:

```
               58         ------>64   
              /   \      |      /   \
            22     73    |    22     58
           /  \   /  \   |   /  \   /  \
          19  36 64  81  |  81  73 36  19
                  |______|
```

Otherwise I'd need to find the node in the right tree in `n` time, because it isn't sorted by the left digit.

My `Tree` class doesn't allow direct access to nodes, only to data (and I'd like to keep it that way).

Do I have no choice but to implement my data structure as a `friend` class of the `Tree` class? Would that even work? Or is there some elegant way of doing something like this?

Comment: Just to clarify... what are the other data types involved here?

Comment: Ideally, you would put the pointers to those pairs of numbers in the tree, and not the numbers themselves. You would make the first tree using the first number as the sorting criterion and the second tree using the second number. However, since your "_`Tree` class doesn't allow direct access to nodes, only to data_", you're going to have to come up with some additional data structure to map tree nodes to tree nodes, like `std::unordered_map` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I plan on doing, if anybody should come across this question...

If I get any persuasive comments on why this is a bad idea, I'll remove the answer / edit it.

Basically, I'll create a `Forrest` class, which is in essence a `List` with the data itself, along with an inner list of specialized AVL trees (`Sapling`s), and I'll make the `Forrest` a `friend` of said `Sapling`s.

```
       _______________ ... _______
Data: |19     |22     |...|81     |
      |PTR->M7|PTR->M2|...|PTR->M1|
      |PTR->N1|PTR->N2|...|PTR->N7|
           _____
Saplings: |T1|T2|

T1:
                       N4:PTR->58
                     /            \
            N2:PTR->22             N6:PTR->73 
            /        \               /      \
      N1:PTR->19   N3:PTR->36  N5:PTR->64  N7:PTR->81

T2:
                       M4:PTR->64
                     /            \
            M2:PTR->22             M6:PTR->58 
            /        \               /      \
      M1:PTR->81   M3:PTR->73  M5:PTR->36  M7:PTR->19
```

Also, I'll create a `Compare` class so different instances of the same `Tree` type may sort differently, and allow the `Forrest` to define the `Sapling`'s method of sorting pointers to the data.

Basic AVL tree:

```
// Base AVL type, incomplete but for the purpose of this question it'll do
template<typename T>
class AVL {
public:
    // Compare type, so different trees can sort differently
    class Compare {
    public:
        virtual bool less(const& T, const& T) = 0;
        virtual bool equal(const& T, const& T) = 0;
    };
protected:
    // Default compare type, to utilize type T's default comparison operators
    class DefaultCompare : public AVL<T>::Compare {
    public:
        bool less(const& T a, const& T b) { return a<b; }
        bool equal(const& T a, const& T b) { return a==b; }
    };
    // AVL tree node. Will be extended in the Sapling
    class Node {
    public:
        Node *_parent, *_left, *_right;
        T _data;
    };
public:
    AVL(const& AVL<T>::Compare = DefaultCompare());
};
```

Extend it, for use with a `Forrest`:

```
template<typename T>
class Sapling: public AVL<T> {
public:
    friend class Forrest;
};
```

This is the `List` class I'll use:

```
template<typename T>
class List {
protected:
    // A list node: prev, next and data
    class Node {
    public:
        Node *_next, *_prev;
        T _data;
    };
    // The list itself
    Node* _head;
public:
    ... // Setters, getters, iterator... etc.
};
```

Define the `Forrest` class (the Forrest **is a** list, in fact):

```
template<typename T>
class Forrest: public List<T> {
private:
    // Extend the list node to include all the Sapling nodes pointing to this data
    class Node: public List<T>::Node {
        List<AVL::Node*> _sapling_nodes;
    };
    // The Saplings themselves store pointers to list nodes, so the data itself
    // is stored in the main list (the _head field, inherited from List<T>)
    List<AVL<Forrest::Node*> > _saplings;
    // Create a Compare object so pointers to the data can be compared in the saplings:
    class ComparePtrs: public AVL<Forrest::Node*>::Compare {
    public:
        bool less(const& Node* a, const& Node* b) { return a->_data < b->_data; }
        bool equal(const& Node*, const& Node*) { return a->_data == b->_data; }
    };
};
```

Whew...

Hope this works.