# How do I implement polymorphism in a nested class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, nested-class

**EDIT: specific example at the bottom**

The best way to explain the problem is by example (note that solutions for this specific example aren't the answers I'm looking for).

Say I have a base class `Base`, which is basically a container:

```
class Base {
protected:
    class BaseNode {
    protected:
        BaseNode* next;
        int id;
    };
    Node* head;
public:
// ... functionality
};
```

And now I want to derive and improve it, adding an extra data field:

```
class Derived : public Base {
private:
    class DerivedNode: public BaseNode {
        char* name;
    };
public:
// .. some more functionality
};
```

What I want is a `Derived` class with all the functionality of `Base`, but have every node also include a `name`, not just an `id`.

But if I look at an instance of `DerivedNode`, what I *want* would be:

```
DerivedNode = {
    DerivedNode* next;
    int id;
    char* name;
};
```

But what I *have* is:

```
DerivedNode = {
    BaseNode* next;
    int id;
    char* name;
};
```

So `DerivedNode()->next->name` would be undefined!

Not to mention that the `Base` class only handles `BaseNode`s... all calls to `new` and `delete` wouldn't allocate enough memory for the `char*` in `DerivedNode`.

This seems like a very generic problem, is there some neat way of solving this? Most of `Base`s functionality would be really useful even for `DerivedNode`s, so I would prefer to keep the inheritance scheme as it is...

**Edit: A specific example for when this may be useful**

I don't really want to put lots of code, so I'll try to explain... I've asked a question regarding my specific needs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27025694/how-should-i-implement-communication-between-instances-in-c?noredirect=1#comment42575329_27025694) if anyone wants to see an example.

I'm implementing a `List` class. That is my base class. It is templated (the data in each node is templated, and each node also has *next and *prev fields), has an iterator nested class, insertion, removal by iterator location... the works.

I want to implement a `Forrest` class, which is a list of data node (still templated), but each node includes a list of `TreeNode`s that point to the node. I want to do this because the data is sortable and I want to be able to fetch it in `log(n)` time (hence, a tree), but it is sortable in two different ways (say, age and ID number), so I need two tree pointing to the same data.

So: I made `Forrest` inherit from `List`, and derived `ForrestNode` to include a list of `TreeNode`s that point to the data:

```
class DerivedNode: public List<T>::ListNode {
    List<Tree<T*>::TreeNode*> treeNodes;
};
```

The base class `List` doesn't need to know about the new `treeNodes` field, because it is irrelevant to the lists functionality - methods like `swap`, `get_head`, `is_empty` should work the same, and creating a new node should work pretty much the same (need to allocate more memory, but the new `treeNodes` field should never be initialized with data).

The new `Forrest` class, however, will override the base `List`s methods, but only with *added* functionality - for example, after insertion (regular list insertion), a pointer will be inserted into the relevant tree, and then the address of the new tree node will be added to the `treeNodes` list.

Comment: This will be very hard if you really need polymorphism, but since you don't seem to be using polymorphism (`DerivedNode()->next->name`), you might want to have a look at solving this with templates.

Comment: Can you please share some specific scenario where such a design would be helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply turn your Base::BaseNode into a template and provide the type of the `next` member variable as the type argument, like so:

```
class Base {
protected:
    template <class Derived>
    class BaseNode {
    protected:
        Derived* next;
        int id;
    };
    Node* head;
public:
// ... functionality
};

class Derived : public Base {
private:
    class DerivedNode: public BaseNode<DerivedNode> {
        char* name;
    };
public:
// .. some more functionality
};
```

Comment: How would that solve the allocation problem? Say I have an `insert` method in `Base`. It should call `new BaseNode()`... I would have to rewrite the `insert` method in `Derived` to call `new DerivedNode()`

Comment: Can you give an example of what this insert method would actually do? What data does it insert into your data structure? And how do you get the name into the node without overwriting the insert method in Derived anyway?

Comment: The insert method would create a new node and insert it at the head of the Base class (like a list), and the default constructor for `name` is good enough for me, I'll write methods in `Derived` to set/get the name

Comment: I don't see a good solution for this without turning Base into a template, too. I don't think there's a way around that if you want Base to be able to handle the nodes generically.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @stefaanv we can use templates to achieve what you want. Please verify below program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class Base {

protected:

    template<typename Z>
    class BaseNode{

    protected:

        Z* next;
        int id;
    };

public:

};


class DerivedNode;


class Derived : public Base{

private:

    class DerivedNode: public BaseNode<DerivedNode>{

        public:
        const char* name;

        void setId(int val){id = val;}
        void setNext(DerivedNode* nx){next = nx;}
        DerivedNode* getNext(){return next;}


    };

    DerivedNode* derHead;

public:


  Derived()
  {
      DerivedNode* node1 = new DerivedNode();

      node1->name = "Nik";
      node1->setId(1);
      node1->setNext(NULL);



      DerivedNode* node2 = new DerivedNode();

      node2->name = "Aka";
      node2->setId(2);
      node2->setNext(NULL);

      node1->setNext(node2);

      derHead = node1;
  }
  DerivedNode* getHead(){return derHead;}

  void print()
    {
       DerivedNode* tmp = derHead;
       while(tmp != NULL)
       {
           cout<<tmp->name<<endl;
           tmp = tmp->getNext();
       }

    }
};



int main()
{
   Derived obj;
   obj.print();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I asked @Kristian Duske this question in the comments: how would this solve the allocation problem? Specifically, this example doesn't take advantage of the functionality of the `Base` class, you need to write a lot of brand new methods in `Derived`, don't you?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not take advantage of functionality of base class". You know that you can never modify the protected members from outside. You could only do that via child class, and in this I have just depicted a way of updating them. in place of multiple functions you can have one update function.